# Можно ли сделать аргумент метода необязательным?

Tags: java

Возможно ли сделать присутствие аргумента опциональным? Т.е. метод будет работать и если выполнять vasya.SomeMet(arg1, arg2), и если выполнять vasya.SomeMet(arg1). При этом arg2 воспринимался бы при выполнении метода равным null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет такого в java. Оно им не нужно - они не знают, где его можно применить. Если сильно нужно, то пишут так:

```
class Test {
public void SomeMet(int arg1, int arg2) {
  // собственно код
}

public void SomeMet(int arg1) {
  SomeMet(arg1, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) ;)

```
public void SomeMet(String... args) {
  // собственно код
  // args[0] args[1] ...
}
```

З.Ы. Да, я знаю, что это сахар массива.

Comment: Я знаю этот способ. Но он плох. Он не позволяет задать параметры по умолчанию "прозрачно". И нужно много разной логики дописывать.